# Hibernate Configuration from SpringMVC to SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm (damn me) porting a SpringMVC application, deployed as a war in Tomcat to a SpringBootApplication and i'm facing a lot of problems, basically from Hibernate.

The application was made with DAO/Service pattern.
I know Spring boot would like to use Spring data JPA but i don't want to refactor all the application.

The problem is especially that somewhere i get hibernate exception of No Session and more ofter the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role` where  the old SpringMVC application works.

For instance, i have this Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARK")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idPark")
public class Park implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7630704706109692038L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_park", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int idPark;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "nome_park")
    private String nomePark;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private double longitude;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "park")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Piano> piani;
//getters and setters
}
```

In a controller if i call

```java
List<Piano> piani = pianoService.findPianoByPark(park);
```

from my service class with `@Transactional` annotation, i still get the exception

This is how i configured Hibernate

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "it.besmart.epark.persistence" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {
    
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory(){
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"it.besmart.epark.persistence.model"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
 
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}
 
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}
```

I think it's a matter of configuration because the old application works with this schema so maybe with Spring boot we need to configure something else to work with Hibernate.
I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8 and so Hibernate 5.0.12.Final

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fetch a lazily-loaded collection outside of a Hibernate transaction (eg. in view, controller or non-transactional service). You can try annotate the class with `getPiani()` call with `@Transactional`.

Also remember that a good practice is to have only service layer transactional.

Comment: thanks, i changed how i get `List<Piano>`, no from a service class with transactional, but same error

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the required dependencies in the classpath you shouldn't have to explicitly configure hibernate anymore.
So make sure that you have added `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` or `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` as a dependency.

Try to delete `HibernateConfiguration` and add your configuration in your `application.properties` so Spring Boot can handle the setup:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:...
spring.datasource.username = ...
spring.datasource.password = ...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=...jdbc.Driver
```

You can read more about database configuration with Spring Boot here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
Reference for available application properties:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Spring Boot should automatically pick up your entities as long as you don't deactivate it.
If you definitely need to specify a package you can do so with `@EntityScan`. For example we had to do this once our Entities where in a different project than our Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "it.besmart.epark.persistence" })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i'm moving all the configuration to the application.properties but i'm getting `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:` exception and i cannot find the property to set the packages to scan form my entity classes

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you still have problems please post your Spring application class.